# Use Column Alias In Select Statement Calculation Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, alias

Is it possible to do something like `select 1 as foo, foo+1 from dual`

This returns `ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "FOO": invalid identifier`

I have a lengthy calculation  that composes a column and I would like to be able to easily use that value for calculation in a difference column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use an alias directly. One way is to use a derived table:

```
SELECT foo, foo+1
FROM (SELECT 1 AS foo FROM dual) AS T
```

Comment: I'm looking for alternatives if  possible, in this case adding another derived table would be a bit cumbersome

Comment: @BrandonKreisel Other alternatives would pretty much boil down to same approach (using a WITH clause SQL etc) unless you want to define a view for your base query

Comment: @Chandu - Exactly, either use a view, a CTE, a derived table or another physical table